# Feature cleanOnValidationError seems to be dangerous

Tags: flyway

The feature cleanOnValidationError in flyway seems to be really dangerous. For example, you've created a project and enabled it for test and development. Then you forgot it and commited the project. So, this feature passed all tests, because it works only on verifivcation fails and also because test db is ok after drop all old data. And if you have a validation error on production you can lose all your data. Yes, it's usefull option for command line tool, but, I think, it's not a good idea for maven and embeddable version.
What is your opinion on this?

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree it's dangerous.

That's why there is a big fat warning everywhere this option is referenced:

**Warning ! Do not enable in production !**

See: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/validate.html